# Waiting for two events in Selenide

Tags: automated-testing, java, browser-automation, waits

I have code, written on Selenium which waits for the first or for the second event. But all testing framework uses Selenide. The question is how to rewrite such code on Selenide, to avoid unxpectable results accured by combining Selenium and Selenide waits.

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getWebDriver(), timeToWait);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.or(
            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(Table),
            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(Icon)
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep existing approach. `SelenideElement` extends `WebElement` so that all existing conditional stuff will be working.

Selenide does not have own cross-element conditions. Only the ones which are applied to a single element like `.is(Condition.blah())`.

There is also `SelenideWait` waiter but it actually does nothing but runs `FluentWait` with some presets.